# How many planets are populated in the Ori (ex-Alteran) Galaxy?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

As it says on the tin: How many planets are populated in the Ori (ex-Alteran) Galaxy? **Is it just the one or is it several?**

Non-canon sources are welcome.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I look forward to seeing your answer to the question.

Comment: nice tactic, but I don't personally find the question interesting so I won't be putting effort into it.

Comment: Planets circle around stars. Solar systems with a star in the center and probably one or more planets populate a galaxy. Do you really ask for count of planets in a galaxy without counting the Stars? I think planets and (any) galaxy are unrelated.

Comment: All of them, I always assumed, like in Pegasus only more so.  Millions at least.  Isn't that why the Ori were so powerful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least two planets are seen directly; [Celestis](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Celestis) (the homeworld of the Ori/Alterans) and the unnamed planet on which we find [Ver Isca](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ver_Isca) (Tomin's homeworld).

---

Vala also mentions (in [SG1: Crusade](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s9/transcripts/919.shtml)) that there are potentially *hundreds* of inhabited world in the Ori Galaxy.

> **VALA:** *They are building ships and armies by the tens of thousands. The village I am living in is one of many, **on a world among
>   dozens like it.***

Since she's evidently getting her info from Tomin (who seems quite a reliable source of general knowledge about the Ori), we really don't have any reason to doubt her.

Comment: Are Ver Isca and Ver Omesh planets or just villages? Ver Eger would point to villages. That is why I wanted evidence.
But yes, just the second part is enough to accept the answer.

Comment: @MartinHandrlica - I think you're right. Ver = village. That being said, Tomin's homeworld has a different coloured sun than Celestis, which points to it being a different planet. So at least two seen directly and "*dozens"* mentioned indirectly.